# Como fazer divisão de uma string com valor dinamico?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu não sei se é o split que usa, no jquery, mas não estou tendo sucesso. Em meu código eu recebo o valor de ID que vem dinamicamente, quero dividir o ID em dois. Uma parte até o caracter 16 e depois o restante.. como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Por favor, mostre o seu código.

Comment: A função que procura é a [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), mas como já comentado, será melhor se você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o seu código para sabermos exatamente o que precisa e como resolver.

Comment: @Taynara Jaegger adicione o código à sua pergunta por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código a seguir fala por si só.

Ele pega um valor string, sua id dinâmica e reparte entre 2 variáveis(String):

```js
var id = "suaIDgeradaDinamicamente";
var primeiraParteID = id.substring(0,16);
var segundaParteID = id.substring(16);

console.log("ID :"+id+" - "+id.length);
console.log("Primeira parte da id 0 até 16 caracteres :"+primeiraParteID);
console.log("Segunda parte da id :"+segundaParteID);
```

Comment: Muito obrigada funcionou para que eu estava precisando realmente, mais um aprendizado, estava usando o split e não conseguia, agora sei o que uso.

Comment: Ótimo, evitei o uso do split, porque isso não é muito complexo e o substring por ser nativo tem uma melhor performance.